# Passing structs to a function using the pointer operator in C

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, struct, function-definition

In this code:

the struct I have has 2 members and with it, 3 variables are defined.

the values of two of them are assigned by me and the third one should come from a function.

the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stddef.h>
typedef unsigned short      int u16;        /*2 byte unsigned int*/
typedef unsigned char            u8;        /*1 byte unsigned char*/



typedef struct 
{
    u8 id;
    u8 salary;
} Emp;
void Math (Emp *Ptr1, Emp *Ptr2, Emp *resPtr);



void main ()
{
    Emp Ahmed = {100, 100};
    Emp Ali = {200, 200};
    
    Emp Result = {0,0};
    
    Math (&Ahmed, &Ali, &Result);
    printf("%d\n%d\n", Result.id, Result.salary);   
    
}


void Math (Emp *Ptr1, Emp *Ptr2, Emp *resPtr)
{
    resPtr -> id = Ptr1 -> id + Ptr2 -> id;
    resPtr -> salary = Ptr1 -> salary + Ptr2 -> salary;
}
```

> the result is :

```
44
44
```

I'm using gcc toolchain, where exactly am I going wrong?

Comment: (100 + 200) % 256 = 44

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `unsigned char` can only hold values as large as 255.  Assigning a larger value will cause it to be effectively truncated to the lowest 8 bits.

Change the datatype of the members to `unsigned short`.  Then they'll be able to hold the result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually declaring these typedef(s)

```
typedef unsigned short      int u16;        /*2 byte unsigned int*/
typedef unsigned char            u8;        /*1 byte unsigned char
```

you should include the standard header `stdint.h` where similar declarations are present.

Moreover the first typedef even is not used in your program.

The maximum value of an object of the type `unsigned char` is defined like (the C Standard)

> — maximum value for an object of type unsigned char

```
UCHAR_MAX 255 // 28 − 1
```

So if to add `100` and `200` then the result will be truncated to `44`.

Hence you should use at least the type `unsigned  short` instead of `unsigned char`.

Also as the first two parameters are not changed within the function they should be declared with the qualifier `const`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct 
{
    uint16_t id;
    uint16_t salary;
} Emp;

void Math( const Emp *Ptr1, const Emp *Ptr2, Emp *resPtr );

int main(void) 
{
    Emp Ahmed = { .id = 100, .salary = 100 };
    Emp Ali   = { .id = 200, .salary = 200 };
    
    Emp Result = { .id = 0, .salary = 0 };
    
    Math( &Ahmed, &Ali, &Result );

    printf("%" PRIu16 "\t%" PRIu16 "\n", Result.id, Result.salary ); 

    return 0;
}

void Math( const Emp *Ptr1, const Emp *Ptr2, Emp *resPtr )
{
    resPtr -> id = Ptr1 -> id + Ptr2 -> id;
    resPtr -> salary = Ptr1 -> salary + Ptr2 -> salary;
}
```

The program output is

```
300 300
```